# Shared buffer using boost::intrusive_ptr

Tags: boost, c++14, shared-ptr

I have a use case where one thread reads message into a large buffer and the distributes the processing to a bunch of threads. The buffer is shared by multiple threads after that. Its read-only and when the last thread finishes, the buffer has to be freed. The buffer is allocated from a lock-free slab allocator.

My initial design was to use shared_ptr for the buffer. But the buffer can be of different size. My way of getting around it was do something like this.

```
struct SharedBuffer {
    SharedBuffer (uint16_t len, std::shared_ptr<void> ptr)
                 : _length(len), _buf(std::move(ptr))
    {
    }
    uint8_t data () { return (uint8_t *)_buf.get(); }
    uint16_t length 
    std::shared_ptr<void> _buf; // type-erase the shared_ptr as the SharedBuffer
                                // need to stored in some other structs
};
```

Now the allocator will allocate the shared_ptr like this:

```
SharedBuffer allocate (size_t size)
{
     auto buf = std::allocate_shared<std::array<uint8_t, 16_K>>(myallocator);
     return SharedBuffer{16_K, buf}; // type erase the std::array
}
```

And the SharedBuffer is enqueued to each thread who wants it.

Now I think, I am doing lot of stuff unnecessarily, I can sort of make do with boost::intrusive_ptr with the below scheme. Things are bit C'ish- as I am using variable size array. Here I have changed the slab allocator with a operator new() for the sake of simplicity. I wanted to run it by to see if this implementation is okay.

```
template <typename T>
inline int atomicIncrement (T* t)
{
    return __atomic_add_fetch(&t->_ref, 1, __ATOMIC_ACQUIRE);
}

template <typename T>
inline int atomicDecrement (T* t)
{
    return __atomic_sub_fetch(&t->_ref, 1, __ATOMIC_RELEASE);
}

class SharedBuffer {
public:

    friend int atomicIncrement<SharedBuffer>(SharedBuffer*);
    friend int atomicDecrement<SharedBuffer>(SharedBuffer*);

    SharedBuffer(uint16_t len) : _length(len) {}

    uint8_t *data ()
    {
        return &_data[0];
    }

    uint16_t length () const
    {
        return _length;
    }

private:

    int              _ref{0};
    const uint16_t   _length;
    uint8_t          _data[];
};

using SharedBufferPtr = boost::intrusive_ptr<SharedBuffer>;

SharedBufferPtr allocate (size_t size)
{
    // dummy implementation
    void *p = ::operator new (size + sizeof(SharedBuffer));

    // I am not explicitly constructing the array of uint8_t
    return new (p) SharedBuffer(size);
}

void deallocate (SharedBuffer* sbuf)
{
    sbuf->~SharedBuffer();

    // dummy implementation
    ::operator delete ((void *)sbuf);
}

void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(SharedBuffer* sbuf)
{
    atomicIncrement(sbuf);
}

void intrusive_ptr_release (SharedBuffer* sbuf)
{
    if (atomicDecrement(sbuf) == 0) {
        deallocate(sbuf);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the simpler implementation (using `shared_ptr`) unless you are avoiding specific problems (i.e. profile first).

> ***Side Note***: you can use `boost::shared_pointer<>` with `boost::make_shared<T[]>(N)`, which is being [added to the standard library in [c++20](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared).

Note that `allocate_shared` already embeds the control block into the same allocation like you do with the intrusive approach.

Finally, I'd use `std::atomic_int` so you have a clear contract that cannot (accidentally) be used wrong. At the same time, it'll remove the remaining bit of complexity.